# Creating a Struct with a Vector of Predicate functions in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm starting with Rust and trying to implement a struct like the following, where I have a vector of *predicate* functions:

```
pub struct Client<P>
where
    P: Fn(&Deal) -> bool,
{
    clientid: String,
    api_url: String,
    deal_filters: Vec<P>,
}
```

I managed to cobble this together based on various things, and I was previously able to implement a `new` function for these structs when I just hard-code this attribute to an empty vector, but it gets weird when I try construct one of these with real functions:

```
impl<P> Client<P>
where
    P: Fn(&Deal) -> bool,
{
    pub fn new(stings: settings::Settings, filters: Option<Vec<P>>) -> Self {
        let deal_filters = match filters {
            Some(fltrs) => fltrs,
            None => vec![deal_predicates::check_revenue],
        };
        Self {
            api_url: stings.url,
            clientid: stings.clientid,
            deal_filters
        }
    }
```

Indeed, when I try to pass these "default" filters in, I get the following compiler error:

```
`match` arms have incompatible types
expected type `Vec<for<'r> fn(&'r Deal) -> _>`
 found struct `Vec<for<'r> fn(&'r Deal) -> _ {check_revenue}>`rustcE0308
```

In addition, I'm not sure how to declare the type for an instance. I'm unclear on the `type` I am declaring this `Client<P>` to be.

The following is based on trying to follow guidance from the compiler, but it's telling me that the size can't be known at compile time:

```
let client: clients::Client<dyn Fn(&Deal) -> bool>
    = clients::Client::new(cfg, None);

14 |         = client: clients::Client::new(cfg, None);
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

My goal was to provide a set of predicate functions that can be used and offer different predicates for different contexts. I *believe* I could potentially use `Box` to solve the "size can't be known at compile time" problem?

Of course, there are certainly other ways I can solve this problem. In addition, a lot of my thinking about this is based on Haskell, so I probably have the wrong expectations or assumptions here, but I would appreciate suggestions as to a better way to achieve what I want.

---

**Edit: Fixed Version Below**

Thanks to some help below, I wrapped up my functions in `Box` and then my new problem was the error `expected fn pointer, found reference`. I also simplified it to remove the generic trait declaration.

Once I googled and resolved the `expected fn pointer, found reference` error, my code compiled fine. This solution is unfamiliar to me, so I am unsure if it's *idiomatic*, but it seems to work.

**Struct**:

```
pub struct Client {
    clientid: String,
    api_url: String,
    deal_filters: Vec<fn(&Deal) -> bool>,
}
```

**impl new**:

```
impl Client {
    pub fn new(
        stings: settings::Settings,
        filters: Option<Vec<fn(&Deal) -> bool>>,
    ) -> Self {
        let deal_filters = match filters {
            Some(fltr) => fltr,
            None => vec![
                deal_predicates::check_revenue as fn(&Deal) -> bool,
            ],
        };
        Self {
            api_url: stings.url,
            clientid: stings.clientid,
            deal_filters,
        }
    }
}
```

I *also* got it working *with* `Box`ing the `dyn Fn(&Deal) -> bool` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Client<P>
>   where
>     P: Fn(&Deal) -> bool,
> ```

What this says is that a given Client struct has *one* type that is callable. But different lambdas are different types.

So yes, what you really want is a `Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&Deal) -> bool>>`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for this response. I still get "`match` arms have incompatible types" where the function I'm passing in is not `dyn`. Do I _cast_ it to `dyn` or is there some other way to mark it as such?

Comment: Using function pointers (`Vec<fn(&deal) -> bool>` notice the capitalization) will work as well, so long as no environment is captured.

Comment: Your answer got me going in a direction of something that works. I got it working by searching on a new error message, "expected fn pointer, found reference" and casting my function item to a function pointer. I will include my working code in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: @erewok don't box the function pointers, use either the function pointers or `Box<dyn Fn(&Deal) -> bool>`

Comment: Ah, you're right. The answer I posted is not the one I went with. I'll fix it so it doesn't confuse anyone. Any preference between function pointers or `Box<dyn Fn...` here?

Comment: @erewok use `Box<dyn Fn(...)>` when using functions that either a.) capture an environment or b.) could/should be a struct implementing an appropriate `Fn` family trait, although this is only possible in nightly rust. Otherwise, a function pointer will be better.